# TensorFlow layers: using custom(ized) initialization function?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, tensorflow, initialization, initializer

Why does obtaining a new initialization function with `partial` give me an error, while a `lambda` doesn't?

All of these functions:

```
f_init = partial(tf.random_normal, mean=0.0, stddev=0.01, partition_info=None)
f_init = partial(tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer, partition_info=None)
f_init = partial(tf.random_normal, mean=0.0, stddev=0.01)
f_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer
```

Throw the following exception:

```
TypeError: ... got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'
```

(while `...` stands for `xavier_initializer` and the other functions, of course)

When applied to a simple `conv2d` layer:

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, [5, 5],
                         strides=[1, 1],
                         padding="same",
                         activation=tf.nn.relu,
                         kernel_initializer=f_init,
                         name="conv1")
```

However, if I use a `lambda` to obtain custom initialization functions:

```
f_init = lambda shape, dtype, partition_info=None:\
         tf.random_normal(shape, mean=0.0, stddev=0.01, dtype=dtype)
```

...it works without any problems.

Shouldn't `partial` also return a new anonymous function of, e.g., `tf.random_normal` supplied with `mean=0.0` and `stddev=0.01` like the lambda statement does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that the functions `tf.random_normal` and `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer` do not have an parameter with the name `partition_info` which is indeed the case. There is no such parameter (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L259) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L31)).

Your lambda works, because it does not pass the `partition_info` to `tf.random_normal`, which is correct.

Also make sure to not get confused with the functions returning initialisation values (like `tf.random_normal`) and the corresponding initializer (like `tf.random_normal_initializer`). The first one returns floats, the latter creates a callable, that expects a `shape`, a `dtype` and the `partition_info`. When called, this callable returns the normal distributed values.

Your lambda does conform to this signature and thus it works. But when using `partial` the signature of the resulting callable is just the list of parameters that haven't been frozen by the call to partial:

```
f_init = partial(tf.random_normal, mean=0.0, stddev=0.01)
```

Since `tf.random_normal`has the signature:

```
def random_normal(shape, mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=dtypes.float32,
        seed=None, name=None):
    # ...
```

You can use the partial as if it was defined like this:

```
def f_init(shape, dtype=dtypes.float32, seed=None, name=None):
    # ...
```

Note that there is no parameter named `partition_info`, but TensorFlow will try to pass it when calling `f_init`, resulting in the error you got.

To customize things like mean and stddev, you do not need to create a custom initializer, though. This for example creates an initializer, that returns normal distributed values with mean `0.0` and standard deviation `0.01`:

```
f_init = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01)
```

But if you need a custom initializer, e.g. to implement custom initialization logic, you could follow this pattern (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L245)):

```
class RandomNormal(Initializer):
    def __init__(self, mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, seed=None, dtype=dtypes.float32):
        self.mean = mean
        self.stddev = stddev
        self.seed = seed
        self.dtype = _assert_float_dtype(dtypes.as_dtype(dtype))

    def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None, partition_info=None):
        if dtype is None:
        dtype = self.dtype
        normal = random_ops.random_normal(shape, self.mean, self.stddev,
            dtype, seed=self.seed)
        # do what you want with normal here
        return normal

    def get_config(self):
        return {"mean": self.mean,
            "stddev": self.stddev,
            "seed": self.seed,
            "dtype": self.dtype.name}

# Alias to lower_case, 'function-style' name
random_normal = RandomNormal
```

Comment: So I'll always need an initializer, which in fact is a function (like the `lambda`, taking `dtype`, `shape`, `partition_info`) wrapping the actual random function (like `tf.randon_normal`)? Thus, partial does not work because it directly returns the "customized" `tf.random_normal` without some wrapper function?

Comment: ...but the `f_init` implementations utilizing `partial` while covering `partition_info=None` do fail, too. For example the first line `f_init = partial(tf.random_normal, mean=0.0, stddev=0.01, partition_info=None)` leads to exactly the same exception `TypeError: ... got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'`. No matter if I supply `partition_info` or leave it out.